# What method was used here to expand $\ln(z)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series, bilinear-form

On Wikipedia's entry for [bilinear transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform), there is this formula:

\begin{align}
s &= \frac{1}{T} \ln(z) \\[6pt]
  &= \frac{2}{T} \left[\frac{z-1}{z+1} + \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{z-1}{z+1} \right)^3  + \frac{1}{5} \left( \frac{z-1}{z+1} \right)^5  + \frac{1}{7} \left( \frac{z-1}{z+1} \right)^7 + \cdots \right] \\[6pt]
  &\approx  \frac{2}{T} \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \\[6pt]
  &=  \frac{2}{T} \frac{1 - z^{-1}}{1 + z^{-1}}
\end{align}

What is the method that is used to expand $\ln(z)$? Taylor series? Laurent series? Some other techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor series show
$$\log((1-z)/(1+z)) = \log(1-z) - \log(1+z) = 2(z+z^3/3 + \cdots)$$
then let $y=(1-z)/(1+z)$.

The math works, though something doesn't jive with my intuition. I guess what's confusing is that the Taylor series already looks like log but it is missing the even terms. With that, as z goes to infinity the series approaches the divergent harmonic series, which makes sense.

Comment: It’s missing the even terms because it’s an odd function: replace $z$ by $-z$ and your fraction turns upside down, so its logarithm changes sign as well. PS: the Grammar Pedant says that the word in this case is not “jive” but “jibe”.

Answer (score 0):

$$
z = \frac{1+\frac{z-1}{z+1}}{1-\frac{z-1}{z+1}}
$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant Check wikipedia for log(1-z), then for log(1+z), then write down their difference, which is also the log of their quotient and finally read the answer again...

Comment: i could not give you a better elaboration than what @Theo has just posted. since you mentioned Taylor series i presumed you were familiar with the basic log expansions